# Why does my code put false values in int array?

Tags: c++

For some reason I get bad output results from this code.

Here I give the code a highest number and a divider number and I check from 0 to highest number all the numbers to see if any of them is dividable with the divider number and if yes, it stores it. I think the problem is at storing data, I just cant figure out why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int HN = 200;   //Number of which we look for the dividable numbers
int DN = 3; //The divider number
int STOR[3];   //[(int)floor(HN/DN)];   //Storage of dividable numbers
int VAR = 0;    //Array index

void multiples(int HNt, int DNt){

    for(int i=0;i<HNt;i++){
        if (i%DNt==0){
            STOR[VAR]=i;
            VAR++;
        };
    };
};


int main(){

    std::cout<<floor(HN/DN)<<"\n";

    multiples(HN,DN);

    for(int i=0; i<=VAR-1;i++){
        std::cout<<STOR[i]<<"\n";
    };

return 0;
};
```

The output I get is

```
66
0
3
6
73
0
0
0
0
0
0
12
15
18
21
24
27
30
33
...
```

I excluded the remaining code as it is actually correct up to 198
Any help is much appreciated in advance :)

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an index out of bounds. `int STOR[3]` array only has enough space to store three elements; you are trying to store way more than three in it.

Comment: You don't need floor. an `int` divided by an `int` is an `int` not a `float` or `double` the fractional part is lost in the division.

Comment: Minor: 'dividable' is more commonly written 'divisible'.

Comment: Change `for(int i=0;i<HNt;i++){` `for(int i=0;i<std::min(HNt,3);i++){` that way you can only put up to 3 items in `STOR` since you created it to have 3 total items.

Comment: so instead of floor(HN/DN) it should be just HN/DN? Also in int STOR[3] can i implement this?

Comment: use a `std::vector<int> STOR;` and `STOR.push_back(i);` to add items to the vector. Also you should get rid of the global variables.

Comment: @drescherjm is that for increasing efficiency only or is it actually more practical?

Comment: An array is a fixed sized object at compile time. It will not grow if you go outside the bounds. A `std::vector` is dynamically sized at runtime and it will grow when you push_back() to it.

Comment: Aaaah okay, but then how does the STOR[] have 66 indexes? where are the rest stored?

Comment: It's undefined behavior to access the array out of bounds. [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: ***where are the rest stored?*** In practical terms you may be overwriting memory stored by other variables of your program. As far as the language is concerned, anything can happen when you violate rules of the language and have UB.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome.

I've had a little go at tidying up but I'm still a beginner myself so just treat this as some friendly advice!

What Igor Tandetnik says is correct. You haven't allocated enough space in your storage system to allow for all the results to be recorded.

So Imagine you write your first number into slot 0, then slot 1, then slot 2... Now what? After the end of your undersized array there is probably other data on 'The Stack'. Other data being used by your program. And now you write over that, creating undefined results. Then after a few writes and as this is a small program its likely you find unused memory on the stack which is 'free' and that is I would guess why it appears to give you the correct results as you go along.

Why not use a dynamically sizeable container for your storage for example std::vector?

If not at least tie your array size to the largest possible outcome i.e. the dividend... See below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

//Moved your variables out of the global scope. Lots of reasons for this.

//Take in your parameters as referecnes and a pointer to your storage facility. 
static void multiples(const int& HNt, const int& DNt, int* STOR, int& VAR) 
{ 
   for (int i = 0; i < HNt; i++) {
       if (i % DNt == 0) {
           STOR[VAR] = i;
           VAR++;
       };
   };
};

int main() {
    const int HN = 200; //Made first two const as they do not change
    const int DN = 2; 
    int STOR[HN];   //Const variables can be used to size your array 
                    //This is great because now your array size is linked to the dividend(HN)
    int VAR = 0;  

    std::cout <<"Floor : "<< floor(HN / DN) << "\n";

    multiples(HN, DN, STOR, VAR);

    for (int i = 0; i <= VAR - 1; i++) {
        std::cout << STOR[i] << "\n";
    };

    std::cin.get(); //Stop immediate return to allow displayed results.
    return 0;
}
```